# How can one automatically have emacs turn on auto-fill-mode for a git commit?

Tags: git, emacs, mode

I'm wondering if there's a way to have emacs turn on auto-fill-mode when it's launched by git during a commit?  I've looked at the command line options and perhaps I could use --load, or something like that to start with auto-fill-mode, but I suspect there's a better way?  Also, git is set to use emacs -nw at the moment and open in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what Magit's [`git-commit-mode`](https://github.com/magit/git-modes/blob/master/git-commit-mode.el#L655) does:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("/\\(?:COMMIT\\|NOTES\\|TAG\\|PULLREQ\\)_EDITMSG\\'"
               . git-commit-mode))
```

Of course, you may simply want to simply install the [entire package](https://github.com/magit/git-modes) instead of reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Swell, looks like they had the same idea then... I planed on looking into Magit once I had some free time to dedicate to it.  This seemed like something that should be (and is) easy to customize.

Answer (score 0):

There might be *several* ways to do this (of course ;-).  One way might have been to add a hook for Fundamental Mode which checked the directory of the commit message file and if it was in .git/ then tack on auto-fill-mode.  But it turns out Fundamental Mode doesn't have any hooks because it is the barest of modes.

The next idea might be to add a function to any startup hooks.  Which lead me to [Emacs Startup Summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html).  I didn't test any of these, so I can't recommend the best hook to use, or if they will even work, and what might be better would be to:

Instead use `add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist` with the full commit message file name `COMMIT_EDITMSG` and hook fundamental-mode to the opening of that file.